# Interior of finer topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am writing some lecture notes for my topology class, therefore, I would like the proofs to, for starters, make sense. Also, I would like for them to look *nice* with regards to formatting. Below is a proposition that my professor gave in class, however, he did not prove it. In my lecture notes I want to include the proof, so I wrote up a proof. To ensure it is correct and also looks *nice* I have included both the proposition and (my) proof.

> **Proposition:** Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a set and $\tau$ and $\tau'$ be two topologies on $\mathbb{X}$, such that, the following holds $\tau \subseteq \tau'$. If $A \subseteq \mathbb{X}$, then $\text{int}_{\tau} A \subseteq \text{int}_{\tau'} A$.

---

(My) **Proof:** Consider the following two families of sets:
$$\mathscr{F}_{\tau} = \{\mathcal{O}: \mathcal{O} \subseteq A \text{ and }\mathcal{O} \text{ is open in } \tau\}$$

$$\mathscr{F}_{\tau'} = \{\mathcal{U}: \mathcal{U} \subseteq A \text{ and }\mathcal{U} \text{ is open in } \tau'\}$$

Notice, $\mathcal{O} \in \mathscr{F}_{\tau} \implies \mathcal{O} \subseteq A \text{ and } \mathcal{O} \in \tau \implies \mathcal{O} \subseteq A \text{ and } \mathcal{O} \in \tau'$. Therefore, $\mathcal{O}$ satisfies $\mathcal{O} \subseteq A \text{ and }\mathcal{O} \text{ is open in } \tau'$, hence, $\mathcal{O} \in \mathscr{F}_{\tau'}$. So, the following inclusion holds:
$$\mathscr{F}_{\tau} \subseteq \mathscr{F}_{\tau'} \implies 
\bigcup \mathscr{F}_{\tau} \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr{F}_{\tau'}.$$ However, this is simply the definition of Interior, therefore, we have that the desired result: $$\text{int}_{\tau} A \subseteq \text{int}_{\tau'} A.$$

Thanks to who ever can leave some feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is correct, but I would write it a little differently: the definitions of $\mathscr{F}_\tau$ and $\mathscr{F}_{\tau'}$ can be simplified and compressed a little, and in general things read more smoothly if you use words in place of the symbol $\implies$.

> Let $\mathscr{F}_\tau=\{U\subseteq A:U\in\tau\}$ and $\mathscr{F}_{\tau'}=\{U\subseteq A:U\in\tau'\}$. Since $\tau\subseteq\tau'$, it’s clear that $\mathscr{F}_\tau\subseteq\mathscr{F}_{\tau'}$. But then $$\operatorname{int}_\tau A=\bigcup\mathscr{F}_\tau\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{F}_{\tau'}=\operatorname{int}_{\tau'}A\,,$$ as desired. $\dashv$

Comment: Thanks Brian! This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I'm actually using that notation ($\mathscr{F}$) that you had used in a previous answer to one of my questions. Works well!

Comment: @DaltonPettway: You’re welcome!